# Firebase cordova-plugin-fcm android configuration

Tags: git, firebase, github, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am using plugin **cordova-plugin-fcm** in my hybrid mobile app for receiving push notification.

In **ANDROID CONFIGURATION** section of following file of the plugin,
***export*** property has been set to ***true***.
(line no : 44 activity android:exported="true" ....)

https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/blob/master/plugin.xml

Could anyone explain the purpose of setting this value to ***true***.

As a side note, I even changed this value to ***false*** and tested for PUSH notifications. I couldn't see any difference on the behavior. PUSH notifications were received properly.

Actually Security Audit team is asking the reasons for making this ***true***, I need to explain the proper reason if any.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Not sure if you've seen this - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html. Search for "exported" for an explanation of its use. However, if setting it to **false** works for your app then leave it as false. I'd be interested know *why* the Security Audit team wants to know.

Comment: Hi  camden_kid, Thanks for your comment. Actually I am aware of the role of exported: true and false. When export:true for an activity, it can be called by other applications too. So if it is really not required to be called from other applications, this property should be changed to false. Security Audit team wanted to confirm if this is required to be true.